# Does every axiomatic homology theory factors through a chain complex?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

We have two definitions of homology groups:

1. (topological) Via the Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms where we have a sequence of functors from the (sub)category of topological pairs to abelian groups and natural transformations between them satisfying the axioms.
2. (algebraic) As a sequence of functors from chain complexes to abelian groups given by $H_n(C_*) := \mathrm{ker} \partial_n / \mathrm{im}\partial_{n+1}$.

Is this true that every oridinary homology theory given by the first definition may be factored through a chain complex? Do I understand correctly that something like bordism theory (I only heard about it vaguely) is an examples of a (non-oridinary) theory that cannot be factored in such a way?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? For any homology theory $X \mapsto h_*(X)$, you can view $h_*(X)$ as a chain complex with zero differential, but this must not be what you mean.

Comment: You are right, I meant in a non-trivial way such as for simplicial or singular homology. This may be a ill-posed question now that I think about it...